# Resize xib dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3

i am adding a custom marker window with the below code and is working fine..But i cannot set the height width dynamically according to the subviews width.

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {

        let customInfoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomMarker", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! CustomMarker
        return customInfoWindow
    }
```

The view is as below

[image]

The problem is how/where to adjust the height of xib so that it increases as the size of inner label increases?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is depends. Are you using auto layout?
If you are using it maybe you are setting some constraints (after adding it as a subview) that block the growing of the view.
When you are using AL the size of a view is due to its intrinsic content size, this size can vary from the type of view that you are using.
In a label with the number of lines set to 0 and the max preferred with set to a fixed number, the label will set its intrinsic content size to display all the content.
If this label is set to have 4 constraints pinned to its superview, the label will push the superview size keeping the constraint as valid.
If you are not using auto layout, you should call `-sizeToFit` to all the elements anche calculate the height manually and adjust the container view frame.

Comment: Yes i am using autolayout.I have just set constraints to all the size on subviews of xib to increase the superview size but the superview i.e xib file itself doesnot grow as the subviews size increases.. How can i set the max preferred width..i tried in size inspector and its not working